# VBA For Auto Fill

Tags: vba, array-formulas, auto-populate

I want to be able to choose a value in `E4` on the `Invoice` (which must have a drop down list of Client ID, Then I want the Client Name to populate into `B5` the client address into `B6`, The vat number into `B7`, Terms into `E6`

All the info must come from the Customer sheet as shown in the picture

```
Column A: Client no (ID100) 
Column B: Client Name
Column C: Client Address
Column D: Vat No
Column E : Terms
```

I have tried everything but I cant seem to get it right, My knowledge is limited but I did write the invoice program....with help from the internet

**Customer list:**

[image: Customer list]

**Invoice:**

[image: Invoice]

Comment: `I have tried everything` - did it include https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-drop-down-list-7693307a-59ef-400a-b769-c5402dce407b and https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1?

Answer (score 0):

This is deceptively simple if you stretch the boundaries of your preferred solution a little bit.  Instead of entering data in E4, use a combo box.  Set the source row as the ID100 column. - Your ID Column only lists unique IDs with no duplicates right?

If there are duplicates in the ID field then you have three choices.

1. Overhaul the table and clean your data
2. Take a day or week or a weekday to really think about how you want select and/or display the extra information and handle the that you'll encounter complexities

   3  Give the project to someone else

I recommend the combobox because

1. The combo box can intellitype/autofill as you type
2. The autofill perk doesn't misspell, or display anything that isn't in that column that means any lookup is a guaranteed return if the user is not being a dill
3. You aren't looking anything up until the ID is populated so this control acts as an um..... well.... control.  It's a great starting trigger.

using the combobox results you simply use your favorite lookup to get the row number (vlookup, match, find, filter, you get the point)

now grab the values from the community you need and populate the cells.

Done!  Easy right?